# RedirectMatch without last part of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have this `RedirecMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/en/collections/$2/
```

If I visit

```
https://www.example.com/en/products/sofas/greyson/greyson-sofa
```

I'm redirected to

```
https://www.example.com/en/collections/greyson/greyson-sofa
```

What I want is

```
https://www.example.com/en/collections/greyson/
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: The directive you posted already does what you require. You probably have a conflict with another directive (a `Redirect` directive perhaps). Please include the full contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @MrWhite I've edited the post

Comment: Note that you've tagged your question `mod-rewrite`. These are not mod_rewrite directives, they are mod_alias. However, if you do have mod_rewrite directives elsewhere (later) in the file then these will take priority - they are processed _first_ (despite the order of the directives in the file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing obvious in what you have posted that would produce the specific output you are seeing, however, there are other errors in the directives and you may be seeing a cached response. 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so any errors are also cached.

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. So, the redirect you are seeing would be produced by a directive something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /en/products/sofas/greyson https://www.example.com/en/collections/sofas/greyson
```

When you request `/en/products/sofas/greyson/greyson-sofa`, the part after the match, ie. `/greyson-sofa`, is copied onto the end of the target URL to produce `/en/collections/sofas/greyson/greyson-sofa`

You can resolve most of these issues by reordering your rules (but also watch the trailing slashes). You need to have the most specific redirects first. `RedirectMatch` *before* `Redirect`. For example, take the following two redirects:

> ```
> Redirect 301 /en/products/accessories https://www.example.com/en/products/complements/
> Redirect 301 /en/products/accessories/bush/ https://www.example.com/en/collections/bush-on/
> ```

Since the `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, a request for `/en/products/accessories/bush/` will actually be caught by the first rule, not the second and end up redirecting to `/en/products/complements//bush-on/` - note the erroneous double-slash (since you have a mismatch of trailing slashes on the source and target URLs.)

You need to reverse these two rules. (But also watch the trailing slash.)

The same applies to the `Redirect` directives that follow. You also have some duplication, ie. You have two rules for `/en/products/chairs-and-bar-stools/piper/`?